# tkinter.Checkbutton variable

Tags: python, tkinter

Пытаюсь присвоить свойству variable значение. Вот кусок кода

```
def __init__(self):
    def getCurrenValue( screen_area):
        # self.screen_area = screen_area
        db = postgresql.open(db_conf.connectionString())
        data = db.query("select active from screen_coordinates where screen_area = " + str(screen_area))
        return data[0]['active']
    print(getCurrenValue(1))
    # first = 1
    first = (getCurrenValue(1))
    # first = first.get()
    print(first)
    tkinter.Tk.__init__(self)
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    self.wait = 1
    self.setDaemon(True)
    self.start()
    self.geometry('150x150')
    self.title('Calculator')
    self.columnconfigure(1, pad=5)

    tkinter.Checkbutton(text="1", variable=first, onvalue=1, offvalue=0).grid(row=3, column=2)
    print(first)
```

Распечатки все дают "1", а на форме unchecked. Пробовал просто единицу присваивать все равно unchecked. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: 1 - Лучше отделить инициализацию интерфейса (создание, размещение элементов управления) от "бизнес"-логики (т.е. собственно выполнения операций). Всю логику приложения лучше выполнять уже после инициализации интерфейса. 2 - К Checkbutton нужно привязывать не просто переменную Python, в которой что-то лежит, а переменную Tk, например как показано здесь: [The Tkinter Checkbutton Widget](http://www.effbot.org/tkinterbook/checkbutton.htm) (привязка `IntVar` к `CheckButton`)

Comment: И еще, опишите в вопросе, как именно вам нужно чтобы код работал.

Comment: @insolor Нужно, когда variable=1 Checkbutton checked и соответственно наоборот при нулевом значении

Comment: Запрос в базу данных периодически отправляется, или только при старте приложения?

Comment: @insolor Только при старте

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Сначала нужно инициализировать графический интерфейс приложения (создать, разместить элементы управления), потом уже выполнять [бизнес-логику](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81-%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0) (непосредственно, какую-то полезную работу).
2. К Checkbutton нужно привязывать переменную Tk, например как показано в примере здесь: [The Tkinter Checkbutton Widget](http://www.effbot.org/tkinterbook/checkbutton.htm). Потом обращаться к значению в этой переменной с помощью методов `.get()` и `.set()`.

Должно быть примерно так:

```
def __init__(self):
    # Инициализируем графический интерфейс
    tkinter.Tk.__init__(self)
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    self.wait = 1
    self.setDaemon(True)
    self.start()
    self.geometry('150x150')
    self.title('Calculator')
    self.columnconfigure(1, pad=5)

    self.first = tkinter.IntVar()  # Создаем переменную Tk, записываем как свойство объекта, чтобы потом можно было поулучить к ней доступ
    chk = tkinter.Checkbutton(text="1", variable=first, onvalue=1, offvalue=0).grid(row=3, column=2)  # Создаем Checkbutton, привязываем переменную
    chk.pack()  # Также не забываем еще разместить элемент управления с помощью pack() или grid()

    # Потом бизнес-логика

    def getCurrenValue(screen_area):
        # self.screen_area = screen_area
        db = postgresql.open(db_conf.connectionString())
        data = db.query("select active from screen_coordinates where screen_area = " + str(screen_area))
        return data[0]['active']

    print(getCurrenValue(1))
    self.first.set(getCurrenValue(1))  # Устанавливаем значение переменной, НЕ перезаписываем значение self.first
    print(first.get())  # Получаем значение переменной

    print(first)  # Выведет что-то вроде <tkinter.IntVar object at 0x03E78CB0>, так и должно быть, это внутренняя переменная Tk
```

Объекты классов `BooleanVar`, `IntVar`, `DoubleVar`, `StringVar` - это внутренние переменные `Tk`, обращаться с их значениями напрямую (как мы это делаем со значениями обычных переменных Python) нельзя. Значение такой переменной можно получить с помощью метода `.get()`, изменить - с помощью метода `.set()`. Если значение попробовать перезаписать просто присваиванием (не методом `.set()`), то мы потеряем доступ к объекту-переменной.

Про работу с переменными, привязываемыми к элементам управления, можно почитать например тут: [Radiobutton и Checkbutton. Переменные Tkinter](https://younglinux.info/tkinter/variable.php)